# Fast enumeration-array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, loops

Hi I'm trying to loop through an array of objects in an array to try and assign them an value. Im doing this through fast enumeration but when I run the build it succeeds but crashes and points to this line:
  for (SKSpriteNode* var in objects_array)

. Did i mess up the syntax? I'm still new to objective-c. It tells me that var is unused and when i run the build that point is a breakpoint.

(btw I didn't include the code for when I created the actual SKSpriteNode objects left middle and right because they have multiple properties and i thought it may be distracting. I can post it though if needed)

Thanks!

```
NSMutableArray* objects_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

NSMutableArray* value_array  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
[objects_array addObject:@"left"];
[objects_array addObject:@"middle"];
[objects_array addObject:@"right"];

for (SKSpriteNode* var in objects_array) {

    int value =arc4random_uniform(1);

    [value_array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];
}
```

Comment: What line? And what is the error message?

Comment: Oh sorry. This line: for (SKSpriteNode* var in objects_array) {

Comment: You need to initialise those two arrays (eg. `objects_array = [NSMutableArray array];`) - they will currently both be `nil`, which might be the cause of your error.

Comment: I just included that but it didn't help :( same breakpoint with a warning saying that var is unused  @pbasdf

Comment: I am looping through each object in order to assign it a value of zero or one. I'm trying to understand if maybe I made a mistake in how I wrote the fast enumeration or something. How can I loop through all the objects and assign it a value as above @matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems. The first one was said by Rory; you forgot to initialize your variables:

```
NSMutableArray* objects_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* value_array  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

The second problem is that you are working with different variables. Here you say that you are working with `NSString*`:

```
[objects_array addObject:@"left"];
[objects_array addObject:@"middle"];
[objects_array addObject:@"right"];
```

And here you say that you are working with `SKSpriteNode*`:

```
for (SKSpriteNode* var in objects_array)
```

If your sprites are called left, middle and right, you should do this to initialize them (for example):

```
[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"left.png"];
```

And in that case, that should be your for:

```
for (NSString* var in objects_array)
```

Comment: I did initialize the sprites I just didn't include the code since it was pretty bulky. But I see my error now thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the arrays:

```
NSMutableArray* objects_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray* value_array  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: I have done so already I am saying that didn't fix the problem

Comment: You are adding strings to the array, but iterating using an SKSpriteNode.